# MIPS CPI (Compare Enhancements)

Tags: compare, mips

A given benchmark consists of 35% loads, 10% stores, 16% branches, 27% integer ALU operations, 8% FP +/-, 3% FP * and 1% FP /. We want to compare the benchmark as run on two processors. CPI of P1 = 5.05 and CPI of P2 = 3.58.

You are considering two possible enhancements for the Processor 1. One enhancement is a better memory organization, which would improve the average CPI for FP/ instructions from 30 to 2. The other enhancement is a new multiply-and-add instruction that would reduce the number of ALU instructions by 20% while still maintaining the average CPI of 4 for the remaining ALU instructions. Unfortunately, there is room on the processor chip for only one of these two enhancements, so you must choose the enhancement that provides better overall performance. Which one would you choose, and why?

So for this part CPI (FP/) = 5.05 - 0.01(30 - 2) = 4.77

But, I am not able to find the new CPI for ALU.

**Is it -> CPI (ALU) = 5.05 - 0.20 (4 - 4) = 5.05? I am probably wrong about this.**

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This may only be a partial answer because I'm not sure what you mean by "CPI". This could be "cost per instruction", but, I'm guessing it could be "cycles per instruction". And, we may need more information for a more full/complete answer.

The original cost for `FP/` is `1% * 30` --> `30`. The enhancement is `1% * 2` --> `2`. So, the improvement is `30 - 2` --> `28`

The original cost for ALU is `27% * 4` --> `108`. With a 20% reduction in the number of ALU instructions executed, this becomes `0.8 * 27% * 4` --> `86.4`. The improvement is `108 - 86.4` --> `21.6`

So [I think] that answers your basic question.

And, I might choose the improvement for FP.

---

But, I'd be careful with this. And, the following could be wrong, overthinking the problem, but I offer it anyway.

The FP improvement just speeds up the instruction. But, the number of cycles for the `FP/` is reduced and these cycles can be used for other things.

The ALU improvement frees up some cycles that can be used for other things.

In both cases, we don't know what the additional instructions might be. That is, we're changing the percentages of everything after the proposed improvement. We have to assume that the new "windfall" instructions will follow the stated original percentages. But, we may have to calculate the post-improvement, adjusted percentages

We could recalculate things [by solving for unknowns] from:

```
505 == 35*loads + 10*stores + 16*branches + 27*ALU + 8*FPadd + 3*FPmul + 1*FPdiv
```

... *if* we knew the CPI for the *other* instructions (e.g. the CPI for a load, etc.). But, this is missing information.